# Getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header... even though using middleware.CORS()

Tags: go, go-echo

My API is served using the Echo framework. When I do a `fetch` call from my React app, I get

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/myAPI' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

even though I'm setting up Echo like this:

```
    srv := echo.New()
    srv.HideBanner = true
    srv.Use(middleware.Logger())

    srv.Use(middleware.CORS())
```

I tried the following, but I get the same results:

```
var (
    // DefaultCORSConfig is the default CORS middleware config.
    DefaultCORSConfig = middleware.CORSConfig{
        Skipper:      middleware.DefaultSkipper,
        AllowOrigins: []string{"*"},
        AllowMethods: []string{http.MethodGet, http.MethodHead, http.MethodPut, http.MethodPatch, http.MethodPost, http.MethodDelete, http.MethodOptions},
        AllowHeaders: []string{echo.HeaderOrigin, echo.HeaderContentType, echo.HeaderAccept, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowOrigin, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowMethods},
    }
)

srv.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(DefaultCORSConfig))
```

In the response, I don't see the `access-control-allow-origin` header. I get the same results even if I put `localhost:3000` in `AllowOrigins`

Comment: Can you check with `curl -X OPTIONS` to see whether the header is actually sent? You might have to add `http.MethodOptions` to `AllowMethods`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#preflighted_requests_in_cors

Comment: With ```curl -X OPTIONS``` I get ```{"message":"Method Not Allowed"}```

Comment: There is your problem. Add `http.MethodOptions` to `AllowMethods`. Read up a bit about pre-flight requests.

Comment: I get the same error as before, both with fetch and curl. I updated the code with ```AllowMethods```

Comment: https://github.com/labstack/echo/issues/1040 try adding a trailing slash to your request - if that works, maybe something like `e.Pre(middleware.AddTrailingSlash())` can fix it for you

Comment: Good find, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: The `Pre` method is executed before `router.Find`, and after `Use` method, you need to use `Pre` to add CORS processing. Intercept the Option request before the router matches and return 204, otherwise the router returns 405.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `echo.New()` was called again somewhere else in the code, thus wiping out the call to `srv.Use(middleware.CORS())`, which is all you need to allow cross origin calls.

Comment: Beware that `middleware.CORS()` is an *allow-all* policy, essentially disabling CORS. The server becomes vulnerable to XSS attacks.